# Getting Segment fault while rsa sign using Openssl

Tags: c, openssl

I am trying to do RSA sign.
Steps that I am following are:

Creating RSA Key:

```
BIGNUM *check ;

        check = BN_bin2bn(m_priv_n, MODULUS_SIZE, rsa->n);
        if(check == NULL) 
        {
            perror("Error in n \n");
            rv = - 1;
            goto exit;
        }

        check = BN_bin2bn(m_priv_e, EXPONENT_SIZE, rsa->e);
        if(check == NULL) 
        {
            perror("Error in e \n");
            rv = - 1;
            goto exit;
        }

        check = BN_bin2bn(m_priv_d, D_SIZE, rsa->d);
        if(check == NULL) 
        {
            perror("Error in d \n");
            rv = - 1;
            goto exit;
        }

        check = BN_bin2bn(m_priv_p, PRIME_NUMBER_SIZE, rsa->p);
        if(check == NULL) 
        {
            perror("Error in p \n");
            rv = - 1;
            goto exit;
        }

        check = BN_bin2bn(m_priv_q, PRIME_NUMBER_SIZE, rsa->q);
        if(check == NULL) 
        {
            perror("Error in q \n");
            rv = - 1;
            goto exit;
        }

        check = BN_bin2bn(m_priv_dp,DP_SIZE,rsa->dmp1);
        if(check == NULL) 
        {
            perror("Error in dp \n");
            rv = - 1;
            goto exit;
        }

        check = BN_bin2bn(m_priv_dq, DQ_SIZE, rsa->dmq1);
        if(check == NULL) 
        {
            perror("Error in dq \n");
            rv = - 1;
            goto exit;
        }


        check = BN_bin2bn(m_priv_iq, IQ_SIZE, rsa->iqmp);
        if(check == NULL) 
        {
            perror("Error in iq \n");
            rv = - 1;
            goto exit;
        }



            EVP_PKEY *signing_key = EVP_PKEY_new();
        //  EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(signing_key, rsa);

            EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA( signing_key, rsa );
```

Calculating Hash value:

```
EVP_MD_CTX mdctx;
        const EVP_MD *md;
        unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
        unsigned int mdlen;

        OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
        md = EVP_get_digestbyname("sha256");

        if(!md)
        {
            printf("Unknown message digest \n");
            rv = - 1;
            goto exit;
        }

        EVP_MD_CTX_init(&mdctx);
        EVP_DigestInit_ex(&mdctx, md, NULL);
        EVP_DigestUpdate(&mdctx, input, strlen(input));
        EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&mdctx, md_value, &mdlen);
        EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&mdctx);
```

And then signing, for that I have tried with two different approach:
First Approach:

```
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
        OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
        OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

        EVP_PKEY *evpKey = 0;
        evpKey = EVP_PKEY_new();

        EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA( evpKey, rsa );

        EVP_MD_CTX* ctx = 0;
        ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
        EVP_SignInit_ex( ctx, EVP_sha256(), 0 );
        EVP_SignUpdate( ctx, md_value, mdlen);

        const int MAX_LEN = 256;
        unsigned char sig[MAX_LEN];
        unsigned int sigLen;
        memset(sig, 0, MAX_LEN);

        EVP_SignFinal( ctx, sig, &sigLen, evpKey );// Here it is getting crashed

        printf( "Got signature: '%s'\n", sig );

        EVP_MD_CTX_destroy( ctx );
        RSA_free( rsa );
        EVP_PKEY_free( evpKey );
        ERR_free_strings();
```

Second Approach:

```
            EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;
        unsigned char *sig;
        size_t siglen;

        ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(signing_key,NULL);

         if (!ctx)
         {
            printf("Error Occurred \n");
            rv = - 1;
            goto exit;

         }

         if (EVP_PKEY_sign_init(ctx) <= 0)
         {
            printf("Error \n");
            rv = - 1;
            goto exit;       
         }

         if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING) <= 0)
         {
            printf("Error \n");
            rv = - 1;
            goto exit;       
         }

         if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md(ctx, EVP_sha256()) <= 0)
         {
            printf("Error \n");
            rv = - 1;
            goto exit;       
         }

            fflush(stdout);
         if (EVP_PKEY_sign(ctx, NULL, &siglen, md_value, mdlen) <= 0)
         {
            printf(" Error  \n");
            rv = - 1;
            goto exit;       

         }

         sig = (unsigned char*)OPENSSL_malloc(siglen);
         if (!sig)
         {
            printf(" malloc failure \n");
            rv = - 1;
            goto exit;       

         }
         if (EVP_PKEY_sign(ctx, sig, &siglen, md_value, mdlen) <= 0) // Here it is crashing
         {
            printf("Unknown message digest \n");
            rv = - 1;
            goto exit;       

         }
```

In both the above cases, I am getting the same error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000049b5ea in BN_MONT_CTX_set ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000049b5ea in BN_MONT_CTX_set ()
#1  0x000000000049b8f3 in BN_MONT_CTX_set_locked ()
#2  0x0000000000440a6c in RSA_eay_mod_exp ()
#3  0x000000000043fb29 in RSA_eay_private_encrypt ()
#4  0x00000000004050b2 in RSA_private_encrypt ()
#5  0x000000000044169f in RSA_sign ()
#6  0x0000000000443d1f in pkey_rsa_sign ()
```

Any Help to resolve this error will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Yuvi

Comment: comment parts of your code and see where it crashes...

Comment: @neagoegab I know where it is getting crashed.. added comments even. But the matter of fact is whether I am doing it in a correct way or not..

Comment: md_value passed EVP_PKEY_sign comes from where? Is the pointer passed valid?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution: I was not creating the RSA key in a proper way. Following is the right way:

```
    BIGNUM *check ;

    RSA *rsa = RSA_new(); // Create a new RSA key
    rsa->e = BN_new();
    rsa->n = BN_new();
    rsa->d = BN_new();
    rsa->p = BN_new();
    rsa->q = BN_new();
    rsa->dmp1 = BN_new();
    rsa->dmq1 = BN_new();
    rsa->iqmp = BN_new();

    check = BN_bin2bn(m_priv_n, MODULUS_SIZE, rsa->n);
    if(check == NULL) 
    {
        perror("Error in n \n");
        rv = - 1;
        goto exit;
    }

    check = BN_bin2bn(m_priv_e, EXPONENT_SIZE, rsa->e);
    if(check == NULL) 
    {
        perror("Error in e \n");
        rv = - 1;
        goto exit;
    }

    check = BN_bin2bn(m_priv_d, D_SIZE, rsa->d);
    if(check == NULL) 
    {
        perror("Error in d \n");
        rv = - 1;
        goto exit;
    }

    check = BN_bin2bn(m_priv_p, PRIME_NUMBER_SIZE, rsa->p);
    if(check == NULL) 
    {
        perror("Error in p \n");
        rv = - 1;
        goto exit;
    }

    check = BN_bin2bn(m_priv_q, PRIME_NUMBER_SIZE, rsa->q);
    if(check == NULL) 
    {
        perror("Error in q \n");
        rv = - 1;
        goto exit;
    }

    check = BN_bin2bn(m_priv_dp,DP_SIZE,rsa->dmp1);
    if(check == NULL) 
    {
        perror("Error in dp \n");
        rv = - 1;
        goto exit;
    }

    check = BN_bin2bn(m_priv_dq, DQ_SIZE, rsa->dmq1);
    if(check == NULL) 
    {
        perror("Error in dq \n");
        rv = - 1;
        goto exit;
    }


    check = BN_bin2bn(m_priv_iq, IQ_SIZE, rsa->iqmp);
    if(check == NULL) 
    {
        perror("Error in iq \n");
        rv = - 1;
        goto exit;
    }


    EVP_PKEY *signing_key = EVP_PKEY_new();
    EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(signing_key, rsa);
```